# AndEngine physics joint

Tags: android, game-physics, andengine, physics-engine

I use AndEngine for Android,

when i create a scene i place there two physics objects, and i want them to be always at the same distance when they are moving.

I tried to use **DistanceJoint**, but i cant understand how to set length of it. This length is not in pixels... I want to set: `distancejoint.length = "distance between objects in scene initialization"`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Every value (especially positions) needs to be divided by: [`PhysicsConstants.PIXEL_TO_METER_RATIO_DEFAULT`](https://github.com/nicolasgramlich/AndEnginePhysicsBox2DExtension/blob/GLES2/src/org/andengine/extension/physics/box2d/util/constants/PhysicsConstants.java).